# How to bind event to hide menu

Tags: jquery

I have created a small plugin to show a dropdown menu when a div is clicked.

Below is the code to get it to work

```
$('#clickable_div').click(function() {
    $('#nav_menu').showMenu({
        parent:'#clickable_div' 
    });                
});
```

Jsfiddle with the plugin : http://jsfiddle.net/HtNK3/

So now basically i want to add a functionality where i need to hide the dropdown div when user clicks anywhere 
in the document but not on the dropdown div which is open

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

I am using something like this:

```
//Close popup menus by clicking anywhere
$("body").mouseup(function(event){
        if (!$(event.target).hasClass("YOUR_CLASS_HERE")) {
        $("#nav_menu").hide();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hi llia i tried this <body class="myclass"> <div id="clickable_div" class="z">
if (!$(event.target).hasClass("z")) {
        $("#nav_menu").hide();
    }  but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you only have one element to hide you can try this instead:
`if ($(event.target).id != "nav_menu")`

Comment: No llia there will be multiple dropdown's :(

Comment: I doesn't work on jsfiddle for whatever reason. Try it locally.

Answer (score 0):

I would use setTimout when the mouse leaves the dropdown (`mouseleave`event) and then hide the div. Pretty common and easy.

Buggy but basic example:
http://jsfiddle.net/HtNK3/5/